# Calling intermediate attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two tables Projects and Users and i have an intermediate table UserProjects which only contains the id's of users and projects. I need to get the created_at field of UserProject table so that i can show the assigned date of the project to the current user in my view.

i have tried current_user.user_projects.includes(:projects)

```
current_user.user_projects.includes(:projects)
```

It returns me an association but i can't get the value of the created_at field like this current_user.user_projects.includes(:projects).created_at

Comment: I don't understand. If you have `created_at` column on `user_projects` table, its value should be available to get in `current_user.user_projects` association. What makes you think it's not, then?

Comment: Yes it should be but it was showing an error but got it working.

Comment: "It was showing an error" and you didn't think it would be useful to put this error in your question?

Comment: can't get the value of the created_at field like this current_user.user_projects.includes(:projects).created_at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `users_projects` table does not have a `created_at` column then this won't work.
Make the join table a proper model with timestamps.

Then you can do stuff like

```
current_user.user_projects.each do |user_project|
  puts "Project #{user_project.project.name} was assigned on #{user_project.created_at}"
end
```

If a user can only have the same project assigned once, then add a unique index for `[:project_id, :user_id]`

If you want to show a specific project:

```
current_user.user_projects.find_by(project_id: params[:project_id])
```

You can also add a `:through` association for the projects:

```
class User
  ...
  has_many :projects, through: :user_projects
  ...
end
```